# How to dissociate linked objects in a live git repository (Or how to remove the internal reference from a shared mirror)

Tags: git, repo, git-mirror

### What steps do I need to take to remove a git mirror?

I have cloned android and downloaded the full mirror to be able to quicker checkout with `git clone --reference` (With its wrapper `repo init --mirror`) but my mirror contains parts of the code which is not never referenced and too much disk space is wasted here. For instance I do not need to have the prebuilt binaries for MacOS and Windows when only building on Linux.

*I see two possible paths forward please let me know in the comments if I should split this into two separate questions*

**Option 1:** is to decouple the mirrors from all checkouts where the local git repo no longer uses the mirror but have everything contained in its own directories. I think maybe some command line for `git fsck` could be used for this.

I did not use `--dissociate` when creating to clone. Now I want to transform the shared objects to disassociated objects.

**Option 2:** find which modules in the mirror that is actually in use and remove any which does not have any links to it. This could probably be a job for `find`,`grep` and `awk` magic.

I would also like to run above without destroying my working directories just in case there is some change I have forgotten to commit somewhere.

Comment: I was surprised not to find a question about this here, maybe I was not searching with the correct keywords.

Comment: A mirror clone, made with `git clone --mirror`, is a bare clone: it has no work-tree so there is nothing to worry about there. I'm not sure what `repo init --mirror` does. The main problem is that if you did a `git clone --reference` that *used* the mirror clone, that additional repository may be using the object database of the mirror clone. Whether it is, and what you need to do, depend on whether you used `--dissociate` as well: if you did dissociate, the additional clone is standalone and there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to deal with a clone that you *didn't* use `--dissociate` with. Probably your best bet is to clone the clone, with no reference options at all, so as to get a real standalone one. Then, update branches and shuffle origin URL about and so on as appropriate in the new clone, and you can then delete the mirror.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the git clone --mirror this is about the *reference* to the mirror

Comment: `repo --mirror` calls `git --reference` for all modules

Comment: Thanks @torek clarified the question for option 1

Comment: Hm, ok, knowing what `repo --mirror` does, and given that you don't want to re-clone your clones of the mirror clone: maybe the thing to do is enter each mirror clone, update its `remote.origin.fetch` directive to be more selective, and delete any refs you don't care about and then run `git gc` in them. Whether this will be effective (and how effective) depends on the retained commits and other objects.